# Selecting records based on the min value of a column but keep other constraints

Tags: mysql

The `cont` table contains many records with the same `userid`. I am trying to select the minimum distance value from the `dist` column for every unique user ID.

```
SELECT sec.*, r.contid, r.lng, r.lat, **math formula for distance** < $withinMiles AS dist
FROM cont r
JOIN s_cont s
ON r.userid = s.userid
WHERE (( **math formula for distance**))
ORDER BY dist ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use grouping with having clause:

```
SELECT sec.*, r.contid, r.lng, r.lat, MIN(**math formula for distance**) AS dist
FROM cont r
JOIN s_cont s
ON r.userid = s.userid
GROUP BY r.userid
HAVING MIN(**math formula for distance**) < $withinMiles
ORDER BY dist ASC
```

GROUP BY will group together rows with same userid, MIN() will extract minimal value from these rows (i.e. with same userid). HAVING works just like WHERE but on already aggregated values.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. What if I have many other WHERE `constraints`? Also, why do I need a `MIN` in the SELECT part as well? wouldn't that try to get the minimum value of ALL records as opposed to those with a unique id only?

Comment: You can still keep WHERE constraints without any problem. Also, when you're using GROUP BY aggregating functions like MIN(), COUNT() etc. work only on rows grouped by "GROUP BY" statement. That means that result will consist of multiple rows - one for each userid and MIN() will produce minimal distance **per** userid.

Comment: @GerardoLima - why it isn't ANSI? (it may not, I'm not an expert on ANSI). It should work on MySQL though.

Comment: ANSI SQL mandates all columns not used by an aggregate function must be on the group by clause. The ANSI compatible solution would involve filtering with a sub-query, but, since the question is on MySQL and it supports this extension, then there's no point.